# Can Sannyasi wear Gold?

Tags: vedas, sannyasa

I have seen Sannyasis wearing gold jewellery, especially the Jataguru of Sringeri Sharda Peetam (during the Dasara celebration). I am aware that the Vedas state that a sannyasi should wear gold. However, I have been unable to find a specific reference to this injunction. If anyone can share a reference, I would be grateful.

PS: I have great respect for all sannyasis. I posted this question because I am unable to find the Vedic reference that I heard a long time ago

[image]

Comment: Short Answer: No.

Comment: I can't pinpoint exactly but scriptures state that sannyasi should avoid touch of all sorts of metals. This includes iron (arms, weapons, tools, vessels), copper (coins, vessels), silver (coins, jewelry) & gold (coins, jewelry). Although today metal-made kamandalu is commonplace, but in the past they were made out of dried gourd. However, with changing times, strict adherence to this rule became difficult.

Comment: Read  [Darbar](https://www.facebook.com/ShishyavrundaSringeri/photos/navaratri-utsava-is-the-most-celebrated-one-among-all-the-festivals-at-sringeri-/1818892414827270/). Vidyaranya is very knowledgeable of Shastras..So, there must be some exception in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Sannyasis should usually avoid gold.

From Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad's Chapter 7:

> Narada then asked: "What is the discipline of an ascetic?" The
> Grandfather praised him and said in reply: "A man who is detached,
> after he has renounced, should reside in the same place during the
> rainy season, but during the remaining eight months he should wander
> alone and not live in one place. Prompted by fear, a
> mendicant, like an antelope, should not stay in one place. He should
> not accept anything that would hinder his travel. 94 "He shall
> not swim across rivers or climb trees. He shall not go to see divine
> festivals or live in a house. He shall not perform the fire worship or
> travel everywhere. He shall not accept food that has been offered to a
> deity or eat at a single house. He shall not worship
> external gods. Abandoning everything other than himself and obtaining
> his food in the manner of a bee, he shall become lean
> and not put on fat. **He shall avoid** ghee as he would blood, a full meal
> from a single house as he would meat, putting on perfume as he would
> smearing himself with filth, salt as he would a person of the
> lowest caste, a garment as he would an unclean bowl, inunction as he
> would sexual intercourse with a woman, hot water as he would urine,
> covetousness as he would cow's meat, a region where he is well known
> as he would a Candala district, women as he would a snake, **gold as
> he would a deadly poison**, a place of assembly as he would a
> cremation ground, capital cities as he would the Kumbhipaka hell,95
> and a full meal from a single house as he would a rice ball offered to
> the dead.96

[Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad is one of the [Sannyasa Upanishads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sannyasa_Upanishads) and is linked with the Atharva Veda]